# Assign to someone else is enabled in Docusign, but not appearing as an option for recipients

Tags: docusignapi

We've enabled "Assign to someone else" in preferences.

Envelopes created via the UI offer recipients the ablity to assign to someone else.

We explicitly set AllowReassign = "true"  on envelopes created via the API.

Envelopes created via the API do NOT offer this option.

NOTE: We are NOT using the emails generated by docusign: we are sending our own emails then using the API CreateRecipientView call based on a unique token.

If I use "correct" to edit a sent envelope and add a new recipient, this DOES generate a docusign email, and this new recipient DOES have the option to "assign to someone else" on clicking the link.

What is preventing the "assign to someone else" functionality from working? Might it be our use of CreateRecipientView? Is there a bug? Failing that, what other things can I check?

EDIT - as suggested exmaple code of how we create the envelope

```
var envDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition { EmailSubject = emailSubject) };
envDefinition.Documents = new List<Document>();

//Add the email text
envDefinition.EmailSubject = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Title);
envDefinition.EmailBlurb = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Message);

//Add the documents
envDefinition.Documents = PopulateDocuments(documentList, Envelope);

EventNotification evenNotification = new EventNotification
{
    LoggingEnabled = "true",
    RequireAcknowledgment = "true",
    UseSoapInterface = "false",
    IncludeCertificateWithSoap = "false",
    SignMessageWithX509Cert = "false",
    IncludeDocuments = "true",
    IncludeEnvelopeVoidReason = "true",
    IncludeTimeZone = "true",
    IncludeSenderAccountAsCustomField = "true",
    IncludeDocumentFields = "true",
    IncludeHMAC = "true",
    IncludeCertificateOfCompletion = "false",
};

evenNotification.Url = docusignBaseUrl;
var envelopeEvents = new List<EnvelopeEvent>();
// In this case we only add a single envelope event, we can add multiple events based on requirement
envelopeEvents.Add(new EnvelopeEvent { EnvelopeEventStatusCode = EnvelopeEventStatusCompleted, IncludeDocuments = "true" });
envelopeEvents.Add(new EnvelopeEvent { EnvelopeEventStatusCode = EnvelopeEventStatusVoided, IncludeDocuments = "false" });
envelopeEvents.Add(new EnvelopeEvent { EnvelopeEventStatusCode = EnvelopeEventStatuDeclined, IncludeDocuments = "false" });


evenNotification.EnvelopeEvents = envelopeEvents;

List<RecipientEvent> rEvents = new List<RecipientEvent>();
rEvents.Add(new RecipientEvent { RecipientEventStatusCode = RecipientEventStatusDeclined, IncludeDocuments = "false" });
rEvents.Add(new RecipientEvent { RecipientEventStatusCode = RecipientEventStatusCompleted, IncludeDocuments = "false" });
evenNotification.RecipientEvents = rEvents;

envDefinition.EventNotification = evenNotification;

//Add the recipients
envDefinition.Recipients = PopulateRecipients(Envelope);
//envDefinition.RecipientsLock = "true"; //cannot add new receipients at docusign
envDefinition.AllowReassign = "true";
envDefinition.Status = "created";


//submit the envelope
envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);
envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(_docuSignAccountId, envDefinition);
```

and the recipients (Signers)

```
Signer signer = new Signer();
signer.Name = Recipient.GetRecipientName(recipient.TheRecipient);
signer.Email = Recipient.GetRecipientEmail(recipient.TheRecipient);
signer.RecipientId = recipient.Id.ToString();
signer.TemplateLocked = "true"; //cannot be edited as docusign
signer.TemplateRequired = "true"; //cannot be removed at docusign
signer.EmailNotification = new RecipientEmailNotification()
{
    SupportedLanguage = GetLanguage(recipient),
    EmailSubject = string.Format(WebDisplayHelper.GetText(typeof(DocuSignFileHandler), DocuSignFileHandlerResources.EmailSubject),
                                  HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Envelope.Title),
                                  HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Envelope.Reference)),
    EmailBody = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Envelope.Blurb)
};
signer.RoutingOrder = recipient.RoutingOrder.ToString();
```

This code works in general - in addition to enabling "Allow recipients to change signing responsibility" in Settings, the only code change is that we've commented out the code which locks recipients, and added the explicit call

```
    envDefinition.AllowReassign = "true";
```

Ideally we would retain the lock so that new recipients cannot be added, while allowing specified receipients to reassign the signature to someone else

Comment: What is the code of your API call to create the envelope?

Comment: @hiew1, I've updated the question with example code, thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Signer Reassign feature does disappear under certain circumstances. If you're sending the email notifications on your own and utilizing recipientViewTokens, that means that you're most likely using captive recipients. What makes a captive recipient captive is the existence of a clientUserId, which enables recipientViewTokens and stops the initial email notifications from going out.

One of the other things it does is that the envelope is bound to a generic DocuSign account, not to any particular users personal DS account. Because the DS account / user seat is *required* for signer reassign the option is removed.

Feel free to open up a ticket on the support portal to discuss in realtime, myself or someone from my team can meet with you to go over the issue.

Regards,

Matt

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'd already come to that conclusionhaving raised a ticket. We are making changes to our API usage and will consider this as part of that work, as it looks like we might be moving towards DS user accounts rather than (as you suggest) the generic account we currently use